# $_SERVER doesn't work for me

Tags: php

im using the below code to get the clients ip when i try to get my ip thru this it says 103.245.196.41 but my actual ip is 10.100.210.5. My code:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER)`.  What do you see?

Comment: i see my ip as 103.245.196.41

Comment: Are you testing this code on a remote server (internet) from your machine? Or the server is on your machine?

Comment: @JorgeCampos on a remote server

Comment: So, @grebneke has answered you. And for your question, on his answer's comment, it maybe possible if your application get it from an java code (through javascript) and send it to the server before your code. But you shouldnt relie on this info.

Comment: @JorgeCampos is correct, [it can sometimes be done](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?242538-Getting-local-IP-address-in-javascript). But it is unreliable, and above all useless. Thousands of clients will have the same internal ip on some reserved ip range, like 192.168.0.0 or 10.0.0.0.

Comment: Yeah thats why I said that he shouldnt relie on it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably behind a router doing address translation ([NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT)). 10.100.210.5 is a [reserved internal ip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) which cannot be used on the internet. 103.245.196.41 is the external ip of your router, assigned to you by your ISP (Internet Service Provider).

So, your computer (10.100.210.5) accesses your script through the router which masks your internal ip and shows the external (103.245.196.41) ip.

When data comes back from the internet to you, the NAT router knows to send it back to your computer on the local network.

This is *a good thing*, allowing you to have a private network which nobody can access from the outside.

Comment: is there a way to get actual ip?

Comment: Actual IP won't be particularly helpful, as many people around the world are likely to have 10.100.210.5 as their IP address. What's the specific business case for needing this

Comment: On the internet, 103.245.196.41 *is* your actual ip. You cannot reliably detect the internal (secret) ip behind a NAT router. What are you trying to do, why do you need the internal ip?

Comment: im trying to build a community website so most of the users that will be accessing my site will have the same ISP. so this means i cant get any one's ip ?

Comment: Having the same ISP is not the same as having the same ip. Each account with the ISP will have a unique ip. Anyone accessing the internet from your home will have the same outgoing ip, but your neighbour will have another ip even if you both have the same ISP.

Comment: You can still get the ip of each visitor. It is frequently done for logging purposes. Just remember that the ip is often dynamically allocated, meaning that [it can change at any time](http://superuser.com/questions/590391/why-do-isps-change-your-ip-address).